# Unexpected Token - After updating dependencies in react native to latest versions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I am trying to import a very old react-native project. I updated the expo version to 36 and updated almost the dependencies to the latest version. It was a working code but upon running now, I get the following error in the below line

Unexpected token (59:18)

```html
  57 |     navigationOptions:{
  58 |       drawerLabel: "Change Format",
> 59 |       drawerIcon: <Icon name="list" size={20} color={TXT_COLOR_PRIMARY} />,
     |                   ^
  60 |     },
  61 |   },
  62 |   Stops :{
```

Failed building JavaScript bundle.

Please find my App.js file

```html
 {
  "name": "AwesomeProject",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.41.0",
    "jest-expo": "36.0.0",
    "react-native-scripts": "^1.14.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.0-alpha.1"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "jest",
    "flow": "flow"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.3",
    "eslint-cli": "^1.1.1",
    "expo": "^36.0.0",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.12",
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-audio-player-recorder-no-linking": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8",
    "react-native-file-uploader": "0.0.2",
    "react-native-flexi-radio-button": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-material-buttons": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-material-ui": "^1.30.1",
    "react-native-permissions": "^2.0.10",
    "react-native-radio-button": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-simple-radio-button": "^2.7.4",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-sound-player": "^0.10.4",
    "react-native-sound-recorder": "^1.3.4",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-tts": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-upload-file": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.3.0",
    "react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.4"
  }
}
```

Import statements in App.js

```html
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet,Image, TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';
import {Radio, Right, ListItem} from 'native-base';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
import { TextButton, RaisedTextButton } from 'react-native-material-buttons';
import { StackNavigator,DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation'; // Version can be specified in package.json
import { Button, ThemeProvider } from 'react-native-material-ui';
import HomeScreen from './Screens/HomeScreen';
import Screen2 from './Screens/Screen2';
import Screen3 from './Screens/Screen3';
import Screen4 from './Screens/Screen4';
import Settings from './Screens/Settings';
import Stop_Info_Screen from './Screens/Stop_Info_Screen';
import AboutUsScreen from './Screens/AboutUs';
import FeedbackScreen from './Screens/Feedback';
import DrawerContent from './Additional_Components/SideDrawer'
import styles from './Styles/commonStyles';
import {COLOR_PRIMARY,COLOR_SECONDARY,TXT_COLOR_PRIMARY,TXT_COLOR_SECONDARY,DARK_PRIMARY_COLOR} from './constants';
```

I started working on react native only from yesterday. I apologize if this is silly. I tried googling this but I believe it is a very generic error. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try adding `()` around the `<Icon />` tag,example : `(<Icon 'content' />'`)

Comment: I added but that doesn't seem to work. Same error.
drawerIcon: (<Icon name="list" size={20} color={TXT_COLOR_PRIMARY} />),

Comment: What's in your babel config - `babel.config.js`?

Comment: I don't have the file @satya164. However, I have .babelrc which contains the following. Yes, I commented them but uncommenting them leads to another error and i think it is independent of this.


{
  //  "presets": ["babel-preset-expo"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
       //"plugins": ["transform-react-jsx-source"]
    }
  }
}

Comment: Delete the babelrc, init a new project with expo and copy the babel.config.js from there

Comment: Thanks @satya164 but like I expected i got the following error.

Unable to resolve "@expo/vector-icons/Fontisto" from "node_modules\native-base\dist\src\basic\IconNB.js". How do I resolve this?

Comment: Install @expo/vector-icons

Comment: I installed "@expo/vector-icons": "^4.1.1",and I get the following error.

Unable to resolve "@expo/vector-icons/AntDesign" from "node_modules\native-base\dist\src\basic\IconNB.js"